# Analytic function on an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, analytic-functions

Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function.Then which of the following are true?

$(a)$ If $f$ is one-one, then $f(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{C}$

$(b)$ If $f$ is onto, then $U=\mathbb{C}$

$(c)$ If $f$ is onto, then $f$ is one-one.

$(d)$ If $f(U)$ is closed in $\mathbb{C}$ then $f(U)$ is connected.

My solution:

$(a)$ $f$ is one-one implies it is non constant and by open mapping theorem $f(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{C}$

For $(b)$ and $(c)$ , I have the following idea:-

Let $f(z)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$. Then it has $n$ roots in $\mathbb{C}$.

Now let $z_o$ be a particular zero of $f $ and$U=\mathbb{C}\setminus \{z_o\} $ is open. Then $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a counter eg to $(b)$ and $(c)$

$(d)$ If $f$ is constant, then $(d)$ is obviously true. If non-constant, then $f(U)$ is clopen set in $\mathbb{C}$ which are only $\mathbb{C}$ or $\phi$ . The latter set is absurd, so image is $\mathbb{C}$ and hence connected. Thus $(d)$ is true.

All I want is verification or improvement of my answer. I would like to know any alternative ideas.Thanks for your time.

Comment: As a counter to (b) and (c) I thought of $f(z)=z^2$ with $U=\Bbb C \setminus \{z\in \Bbb R: z\le -1\}.$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy . (d) is incorrect. See my A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer to (d) is incorrect; you mistakenly assumed that $f[U]$ must be open if $f$ is not constant. Suppose $U=V_1\cup V_2$ where $V_1, V_2$ are disjoint open non-empty subsets of $\Bbb C,$ with $f[V_1]=\{1\}$ and $f[V_2]=\{2\}.$